# Ajax call in wordpress not working for subscriber user in front site

Tags: ajax, user-roles

i have simple wordpress form to add data in custom table in wordpress using Ajax

my Ajax code

```
jQuery.ajax(ajax_object.ajax_url, {
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);

    },
    error: function (error) {
        if (typeof console === "object") {
            console.log(error);
        }
    },
    complete: function () {
    }
});
```

my php code to save data

```
 if (!class_exists('bookly_appo_Ajax')) {
    class bookly_appo_Ajax
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
        }

        public function init()
        {
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ajax_booklyapp');
            function enqueue_ajax_booklyapp($hook)
            {

                wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script-booklyapp', plugins_url('/ajax.js?v=' . rand(), __FILE__), array('jquery'));
                wp_localize_script('ajax-script-booklyapp', 'ajax_object',
                    array(
                        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
                    )
                );
            }

            add_action('wp_ajax_add_category_bookly', 'add_category_bookly_callback');
            function add_category_bookly_callback()
            {
                $storeid = $_REQUEST['storeid'];

                $rows = $wpdb->insert(
                    $table_category, array(

                        'store_id' => $storeid,
                    )
                );
                $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my question is

1. when login with admin my ajax work fine but when login with other user(subscriber user) of my site it's give error "Opps!You do not have sufficient perissions to access this 
   page"
2. which type of accessibility provide to subscriber to used admin-ajax.php  file

Comment: To add to Jordan Lejuwaan's correct answer, the absolute reference to $this in your init method is unneccessary, you can move enqueue_ajax_booklyapp() outside of it's parent function and if I'm not mistaken won't this code throw a parse error?  You have the add_action outside of a function inside a class, you can put it in your init method.

Comment: `class bookly_appo_Ajax` is accessible for everybody? Are you sure you do not have a condition that filters users by role / capability?

Comment: @aifrim yes class `bookly_appo_Ajax` is accessible for everybody. Not put any condition or filter for users by role/capability.

Comment: The error message "Opps! You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" (presumed typos fixed) is not a WP message. You must be using a plugin or theme that is causing the problem.

Comment: @bonger This is a [core message](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=You+do+not+have+sufficient+permissions). At least in theory. Ankur probably didn't copy paste it and has a typo as `Opps` is nothing that is in core and messages that start with `Oops` have nothing to do with permissions. Or maybe it's an outdated message.

Comment: @ankur First: Always [edit] your question if you have additional information, something that you tried, etc. Do **not** add comments for such info. In the end I have to clean that comment flood up and you get flagged by the Community bot for a comment explosion.

Comment: @kaiser Or maybe it's from a plugin or theme!

Comment: Ankur: Turn off all plugins and switch to a default Twenty* theme.

Comment: @ kaiser you are right it's theme problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For non-admin users to be able to use an ajax function, you need to also include a second hook using [wp_ajax_nopriv](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

So right after this:

`add_action('wp_ajax_add_category_bookly', 'add_category_bookly_callback');`

you should include this:

`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_category_bookly', 'add_category_bookly_callback');`

Comment: @ Jordan Lejuwaan add action wp_ajax_nopriv_add_category_bookly is not working. it's return same alert "Opps!You do not have sufficient perissions to access this page".
any other solution?

Comment: but when admin user is login is working currently..

Comment: @ankur - Where are you seeing that error? As an ajax response?

Comment: yes error display in ajax response when i alert the response is say "Opps!You do not have sufficient perissions to access this page"

Comment: When you call your `jQuery.ajax` function, what is in your `data` parameter?  You would at a bare minimum need to provide `{ action: 'add_category_bookly' }` in there somewhere...  If you could provide a sample request header (in Chrome, with Developer Tools, you would find this under the Network tab), with sensitive info. like cookies scrubbed, it might be helpful.

Comment: @ justin bell my data parameter is like this  var data = {action: 'add_category_bookly',...} it's working for admin user but not working with subscriber user only

Comment: Please copy/paste the full response you're getting from the Developer tools and put it in a pasteBin